# jQuery validator, how to validate a disabled <select>

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

html:

```
<select disabled required name="test" id="test">
        <option value="test" selected>
            test
        </option>
    </select>
```

script:

```
$('#project_add_form').validate({

errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    }

});
```

jQuery is validating all the fields, excluding the disabled field, how can I make him to validate the disable field?

Comment: I don't get you. If you have added disabled they no one can change it. then what the need for validation.

Comment: because its disabled for a short time, the user should change other select to enable this, but after this happens I don't want the user to submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot submit the disabled input field values in HTML.*

So try to avoid it.